# target.addEventlListener("click", () =>{ Not working?

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, addeventlistener

I am trying to create a slideshow but the addEventListener is not working !!
i am beginner in js world and want to get better by projects but this simple project has stumped me.

```
const nextBtn = document.querySelector(".next-btn");

const prevBtn = document.querySelector(".prev-btn");

const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");

const slider = document.querySelector(".slider");

const slideIcons = document.querySelectorAll(".slide-icon");

// selecting total number of slides
const numberOfSlides = slides.length;
// whatever
const slideNumber = 0;

// manual functionality
// next-btn

nextBtn.addEventListener("click" ,() => {
  
    slides.forEach(slide =>{
        
        slide.classList.remove("actve");
        
    });
    slideIcons.forEach((slideIcon) => {
        slideIcon.classList.remove("active");
      });
})
```

Comment: You could try to add a console log before the `addEventListener` to see if `nextButton` is the right element, then you could try to add antoher one in the callback of the event to see if it is triggered

Comment: Are you sure is `actve` and not `active` the first class you try to remove?

Answer (score 0):

I don't got the whole situation but as I see your need to add event Listener to your slider so am gonna give you ex about range slider event handler

```
// this stores the value at startup (which is why you're always getting 1)
var rangeInput = document.getElementById("rangeinput").value;
```

You should be reading the value in the handler instead:

```
function testtest(e) {
    // read the value from the slider:
    var value = document.getElementById("rangeinput").value;
    // now compare:
    if (value > 0 && value < 5) {
        alert("First");
    } else {
        alert("Second");
    }
}
```

now **Updating rangevalue**

It also looks like you want to update the [output element](https://newbedev.com/output-element-from-array-python-code-example) with the value of the range. What you're currently doing is referring to the element by id:

```
onchange="rangevalue.value=value"
```

However, as far as I know, this isn't standard behavior; you can't refer to elements by their id alone; you have to retrieve the element and then set the value via the DOM.

Might I suggest that you add a [change listener](https://newbedev.com/javascript-on-change-listener-jquery-code-example) via javascript:

```
rangeInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
    document.getElementById("rangevalue").textContent = rangeInput.value;
}, false);
```

Of course, you'll have to update the code to use **addEventListener** or **attachEvent** depending on the browsers that you want to support; this is where JQuery really becomes helpful.

Use the **mouseup** event for that.
var rangeInput = document.getElementById("rangeinput");

```
rangeInput.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    if (this.value > 0 && this.value < 5) {
        alert("First");
    } else{
        alert("Second");
    }
});
```

You can also use the FORMs *oninput* method:

```
<form oninput="result.value=parseInt(a.value)+parseInt(b.value)">
  <input type="range" name="b" value="50" />100 +
  <input type="number" name="a" value="10" /> =
  <output name="result"></output>
</form>
```

This has an advantage over **onclick/onmouseup** because it handles the case where the slider is moved using the keyboard (tab to the input and use the arrow keys)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your html elements an id and then use `getElementById` instead of `querySelector`